# Porque me salta este error al utiliazr parse de JSP?

Tags: jsp, eclipse, maven, jstl

Tengo un proyecto hecho con Maven y un servidor Glassfish, en Maven tengo este pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>cat.institutmarianao</groupId>
    <artifactId>clima</artifactId>

    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>clima</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Y ahora tengo este fichero .jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" prefix="x"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>El tiempo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:import
        url="http://www.aemet.es/es/api-eltiempo/prediccion/2020-10-27/PB/8/6908"
        var="tiempo" />
    <x:parse var="doc" xml="${tiempo}" />
</body>
</html>
```

Me salta este error a la hora de ejecutar en el .jsp en mi servidor Glassfish:

```
exception: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jstl:; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; El contenido no está permitido en el prólogo.

root cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jstl:; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; El contenido no está permitido en el prólogo.
```

Mi proyecto se llama "clima", están todos los nombres de variables y demás bien escritos, en el web.xml no tengo nada ya que no me hace falta, alguien sabe como puedo arreglar este error? Si elimino la línea de <x:parse var="doc" xml="${tiempo}" /> no me peta el programa.

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: intenta agregar un try{ }catch( ){ } para ver mas especifico que causa el error

Comment: de igual manera aca hay un problema similar con posibles soluciones https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138696/org-xml-sax-saxparseexception-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog